# Family of circles passing through two points

Tags: geometry, circles

Find the equation of family of circle center at (h,k) passing through the origin and (0,4).
So I obtained that the center would be at (h,2). Which has an equation of

(x-h)^2 + (y-2)^2 = r^2

But how can I restrict the above equation, so that all the circles will pass through the origin and (0,4)?

I also tried the S1 + LS2 = 0 and obtained
x^2 + y^2 - 4y - L4x = 0
I don't if it is the right equation to find the differential equation of the family of circles.

Comment: Just replace $r^2$ by the corresponding expression depending on $h$. Have a look here and use the slider: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s19iccmp8g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two conditions that help define this family of circles

1. The center of any circle lies on the perpendicular bisector of $(0,0)$ and $(0,4)$ - hence you get the following set of circles

$$(x-h)^2 + (y-2)^2 = r^2$$

2. The origin lies on the circle

$$h^2 + 4 = r^2$$

So now you can write the above family of circles in terms of parameter $h$, which represents the $x$ coordinate of it's centre (or location along the perpendicular bisector)

$$S_h : (x-h)^2 + (y-2)^2 = h^2 + 4$$

This is the equation in terms of $h$ - where each value of $h$ will give you a unique circle satisfying the condition

Comment: Good gracious, thanks for clearing this out. I've been staring at that  h^2+4=r^2 on my paper without knowing what to do with it. Thank you.